# can't seem to access value outside of function, nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am looking to get back the value "bearerToken" from the function "accesstokenAuth()". My issue is I'm not sure how to get that value out of a function even when I return/resolve it. Here is my code:

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const http = require("http");
const request = require('request');
const querystring = require('querystring');
const { post } = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const { response } = require('express');
const https = require('follow-redirects').https;


//sets express server vars
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Server Connected')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Now serving on ${port} at ${process.env.URI} `)
})


require('dotenv').config();


//authenticate to SpotifyAPI
var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.SECRET_ID,
  redirectUri: process.env.URI,
});

const scope = 'user-read-private user-read-email ';
const authUrl = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=client_credentials';

//Headers needed to auth to SpotifyAPI for Bearer token
const tokenHeaders = {
  'Authorization': process.env.ACCESSTOKEN,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

};


//spotify Auth Payload
const options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'url': authUrl,
  'headers': tokenHeaders
};

//does the function that calls this function need to be async??
const accessToken = async function accessTokenAuth() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     request(options, (error, response) => {
        if (error) throw new Error(error);
        const accessTokenBody = response.body;
        const obj = JSON.parse(accessTokenBody);
        const bearerToken = ("Bearer " + obj.access_token);
        resolve(bearerToken)
     });
  })
}

let bearer = bearerToken;
console.log(bearer)



//Add first playlists request using the bearer token



const playlistUrl = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists'

const playlistHeaders = {
  'Authorization': bearer,
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

const playlistAuth = {
  'method':'GET',
  'url': playlistUrl,
  'headers': playlistHeaders

}




function getUserPlaylists() {
  request( playlistAuth, (error, response) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    const userPlaylistData = response.body;
    console.log(userPlaylistData)

  });
}

getUserPlaylists()
```

As you can see I need to take the "bearerToken" value and then present it to the function below that called "getUserPlaylist" so I can get further data after authenticating. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `bearerToken` is out of scope since it is scoped within your function.

if you `return resolve(bearerToken)` within your function then `accessToken` should equal your `bearerToken`.

Side note, you can rewrite your function like so.

I could be wrong but I don't think that you need the promise.

```
const accessToken = () => request(options, (error, response) => {
  console.log({options, response});
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  
  const accessTokenBody = response.body;
  const obj = JSON.parse(accessTokenBody);
  const bearerToken = ("Bearer " + obj.access_token);
  return bearerToken;
});
```

Comment: I did this and it changed the error but here is the new one.
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
               ^

Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Authorization"]

I'm not sure I'm able to upload a promise as "authorization" in the playlistHeaders

Comment: You have setup your function as `async` but you aren't even using `await`? Have you logged options to see if you successfully pass data in?

Comment: How would you use await in this context?

Comment: You could await anything following '=' but it likely wouldn't have any effect unless if you kept the promise, `return await new Promise`, but I don't think you need it. No point in using async without await.